# using curl command to download file in parts from different interfaces and to run the commands simultaneously from a script

Tags: curl

i wanted to download a file using curl command simultaneously in different parts using ip aliasing(virtual Ethernet ports) so what i did was pasted the commands in a text file and run but the problem as obvious since it is in a file the commands will be executed one by one so is there a way to run all those commands simultaneously. 
here is the command

```
    curl --interface eth0:0 --range 0,38010880 http://wdl.cache.ijinshan.com/wps/download/Linux/unstable/kingsoft-office_9.1.0.4244~a12p3_i386.deb -o kinsoft-office.part1

    curl --interface eth0:1 --range 38010880 ,- http://wdl.cache.ijinshan.com/wps/download/Linux/unstable/kingsoft-office_9.1.0.4244~a12p3_i386.deb -o kinsoft-office.part2

    cat kinsoft-office.part*>kinsoft-office
```

can anyone help me to run these above 2 commands simultaneously from the script so as to increase download speed

Comment: What's the problem with what you've got?

Comment: Adapt this script to your needs: https://github.com/murukeshm/scripts/blob/master/curlwc.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general way of doing things in parallel is to launch each command asynchronously - to run in the background - by adding an ampersand `&` at the end of the command line.

Read up on `job control` in bash manpage and maybe also in the `Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide` (www.tldp.org)